# how to remove the blank space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple list; everything works fine but when I click the button and the list is empy, a blank space appears between the elements. How can I remove it?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Campul este liber!");

        }
        //ListBox li = sender as ListBox;


        ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
        li.Content=textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add(li);

        textBox1.Focus();




    }
```

Code xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Lista.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="325">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,176,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <ListBox Height="111" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,59,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,30,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" />
</Grid>
```

http://i59.tinypic.com/den49d.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem is that you're adding the empty String.** Just return after messagebox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim() =="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Campul este liber!");
            return;

        }
        //ListBox li = sender as ListBox;


        ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
        li.Content=textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add(li);

        textBox1.Focus();




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Campul este liber!");

        }else{
        //ListBox li = sender as ListBox;


        ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
        li.Content=textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add(li);

        textBox1.Focus();
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems with your code.

1. You are only checking if the user hasn't entered anything. What if he enters spaces? For this use [String.IsNullorWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)
2. You are not returning after displaying the message box. For this you need to return after displaying message box.

To overcome both issues. change this

```
if (textBox1.Text=="")
{
     MessageBox.Show("Campul este liber!");    
}
```

to

```
if (string.IsNullorWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
{
      MessageBox.Show("Campul este liber!");
      return;
}
```